# Multi-page application testing using Sencha Test

Tags: extjs, multipage

I am a new user user of Sencha Test started using it few days back using for E2E QA. I have a multi-page application which has a Login page and once successfully logged in another new page opens which has the Menu.

Currently I am able to automate the Login tests using Event recorder of Sencha Test, but after successful login I am unable to access the newly opened Menu page and test its features/contents with Sencha Test.

Any help on how to access the newly opened 2nd page or navigate to the second page after the login page testing is done would be highly appreciated.

I am using Sencha Test 2.0 EA.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use APIs to test the second page. Using Sencha Test APIs you can write targetted tests.

http://docs.sencha.com/sencha_test/2.0.0/api/ST.html

What happens when you try to use event recorder after login?